# Installed Ubuntu on partition. Can't Boot windows 7 anymore

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, boot-partition

I am running Windows 7 on my computer since I built it but a few days ago I was inspired to also try out Ubuntu. I managed to get Ubuntu installed a seperate partition and its running fine. The problem is on boot-up my computer instantly goes into Ubuntu and I have no option to choose between the two. I tried looking into my BIOS but there's nothing there either to choose between the two OS. And I've effectively 'lost' Windows 7, even though its still on the Drive. How do I repair my boot-loader as of now I am able to boot in to Ubuntu only?

Comment: Added an answer, check it and if it works click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "I accept the answer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't see any boot leader and Ubuntu starts directly then you have to edit your grub file. Follow these steps. Press Crtl+Alt+T to open Terminal or search Terminal from dash.

Then enter following command :

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change following lines as (Remove comment (#) before any of the lines given below,change values as below wherever necessary):

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false 
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

Then save the file (<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and run following command in terminal.

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot your system and it should work fine.

Comment: This did it! After a few days of troubleshooting and googling I couldn't find a fix and you got me one in 10 mins flat that worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)  or re-installing the grub. Here is the link for [help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing).